# Changing unit on y-axis from million (M) to show multimillion (MM) in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am binding data to a column chart via Javascript. the Y-axis shows the data unit in millions hence it shows the character 'M' next to the plot point values. I checked the documentation but that didnt help. Is there a way i can format the unit to show as MM for multimillion?

Here's the 'M' on Y-axis that i want to be changed to 'MM'
http://jsfiddle.net/r6V8Z/

Comment: Here it is resolved, http://jsfiddle.net/r6V8Z/1/

Answer (score 5):

Update the Y-axis formatter to this:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value / 1000000 + 'MM';
        }
    },
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
}
```